# XAML Path - Add Text

Tags: xaml

I have made the following XAML path but would like to add the text 'Back' to it.

[image]

This is how I am adding it in...

```
   <Path Style="{StaticResource BackButton}">

   </Path>
```

However when I add any content inside the path I get the message

```
The type 'Path' does not support direct content.
```

Any tips?

Edit - This is the style

```
   <Style x:Key="BackButton" TargetType="{x:Type Path}">
        <Setter Property="Data" Value="F1 M 639.667,236.467L 645.092,236.467L 725.566,236.467L 725.566,253.513L 645.092,253.513L 639.673,253.513L 619.787,244.99L 639.667,236.467 Z " />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30" />
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="100" />
        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="#FFFFFFFF" />
        <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="#FF999B9C" />
        <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="Fill" />
        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Fill" Value="#FFEEEEEE" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can place both the shape and a `TextBlock` inside a `Canvas`, and place the text on top of the shape.

For example:

```
<Canvas>
    <Path Style="{StaticResource BackButton}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Back" Canvas.Top="0" Canvas.Left="25" FontSize="20"/>
 </Canvas>
```

Will give you:

[image]

You can also just use a `Grid` as a container and change the `TextBlock` `Panel.ZIndex` property to a higher value:

```
 <Grid>           
        <Path Style="{StaticResource BackButton}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5"/>          
        <TextBlock Text="Back" FontSize="20" Panel.ZIndex="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>                    
  </Grid>
```

See [this tutorial](http://weblogs.asp.net/psheriff/archive/2010/01/04/centering-text-within-a-wpf-shape-using-a-canvas.aspx) for more details.