# How to create a Textbox and Label with sloped border?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, expression-blend

I am trying do create a Textbox in Wpf that has a Label in its top left corner and addiotionally this label shall have a border with a slope on one side.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tA3Do.jpg
[image: The way I tried it]

Now for one or two specific cases that was doable with a workaround where i just used lines for the border. Now that i want to use it a bit more I need to do it the right way, especially in a way where it is scalable.

I would be really happy if someone could point me in the right direction.

Edit:
So the code I am using after taking into account the responses so far, which i created as a user control:

```
<Grid Height="93" Width="335">
<TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding TextboxText}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Background="{x:Null}"/>
<Path Data="M384,242 L442.5,242" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="1" Margin="0,28.667,0,0" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="59.5">
<Path.Fill>
<LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
<GradientStop Color="#8EFFFFFF"/>
<GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.991"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
</Path.Fill>
<Path.Stroke>
<LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" MappingMode="RelativeToBoundingBox" StartPoint="0.5,0">
<LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
<TransformGroup>                                        <ScaleTransform CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5"/>                                   <SkewTransform CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5"/>                                <RotateTransform Angle="90" CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5"/>                       <TranslateTransform/>
</TransformGroup>
</LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
<GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.009"/>
<GradientStop Color="#5FFFFFFF" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
</Path.Stroke>
</Path>
<Label Content="{Binding LabelText}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="113" FontSize="16" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderBrush="White" Margin="0,0.167,0,0"/>
<Path Data="M125.12574,28.672087 L145.37561,-1.1668457" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30.839" Margin="58.125,-1,0,0" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="21.25">
<Path.Stroke>
<LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
<GradientStop Color="#51FFFFFF" Offset="0"/>
<GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
</Path.Stroke>
<Path.Fill>
<LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
<GradientStop Color="#49FFFFFF" Offset="0"/>
<GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
</Path.Fill>
</Path>
<Path Data="M0,83 L181.35815,83" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="1" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="327" StrokeThickness="2" Margin="0,0,10,10">
<Path.Stroke>
<LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
<GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
<GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
</Path.Stroke>
</Path>
</Grid>
```

It works and the only thing that is still bothering me is the resizability of the label border, which is quite annoying to do but luckily not necessary in my case.

Comment: What you have tried so far? Post the code part here.

Comment: Is the Label the caption of the TextBox? Is the bottom line the only border of the whole thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is another solution which uses a `Style` instead of a `UserControl`.

I assume the `Label` is the description of the `TextBox`, inside the style, I created a `TextBlock` (replacing the `Label` as it would be an overkill in this case) of which `Text` is bound to the `Tag` of parent `TextBox`. Then it will display whatever you put in your `Tag`.

Also I have grouped `TextBlock` and two `Paths` into a `Grid`, set its columns to be auto-sized so you won't have the resizability issue anymore.

The screenshot below is two `TextBoxes` with different labels.
[image]

**The TextBox Style**

```
<Style x:Key="MyTextBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFB8B8B8" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF484848" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="VerticalFirst" />
    <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Border x:Name="BottomLine" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid x:Name="TopPanel" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock d:LayoutOverrides="Width, Height" x:Name="Caption" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{TemplateBinding Tag}" FontSize="14.667" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="4,0,24,0" />
                            <Path x:Name="BottomPath" Data="M384,242 L442.5,242" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,-1.3,0">
                                <Path.Stroke>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" MappingMode="RelativeToBoundingBox" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                        <LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                            <TransformGroup>
                                                <ScaleTransform CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5" />
                                                <SkewTransform CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5" />
                                                <RotateTransform Angle="90" CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5" />
                                                <TranslateTransform />
                                            </TransformGroup>
                                        </LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.009" />
                                        <GradientStop Color="#5FFFFFFF" Offset="1" />
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Path.Stroke>
                            </Path>
                            <Path x:Name="RightPath" Data="M125.12574,28.672087 L145.37561,-1.1668457" Stretch="Fill" Grid.Column="1">
                                <Path.Stroke>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#51FFFFFF" Offset="0" />
                                        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1" />
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Path.Stroke>
                            </Path>
                        </Grid>
                        <Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ListBoxChrome x:Name="Bd" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderFocused="{TemplateBinding IsKeyboardFocusWithin}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Margin="0,0,0,-0.001" d:LayoutOverrides="Width, Height" Grid.Row="1">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                        </Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ListBoxChrome>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**The TextBoxes**

```
    <TextBox Tag="Label" Text="This is a textbox" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="24" Style="{DynamicResource MyTextBoxStyle}"/>
    <TextBox Tag="Long Label" Text="This is a textbox" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontSize="24" Style="{DynamicResource MyTextBoxStyle}"/>
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: This is wonderful and offers way more flexibility than I had hoped to achieve. Awesome, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `Path` and use it as the border, and place a border less `textbox` relative to it.
Please [see my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8068550/xaml-path-add-text/8069628#8069628) in a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

In that case I'd construct a UserControl which contains your desired controls (the two labels and the slope). 
Here's an article on how to create UserControls and reference them in your application:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/UserControl.aspx

If you have Expression Blend you can draw a Slope quite easily, otherwise you have to manually code with WPF's Geometry syntax:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752293.aspx

Here's an example for a slope path which should give a start:

```
<Path Data="M0.5,40 L176,40 M177,40 L217,0.5" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" />
```